# Downloading XML: Python vs Perl vs SSIS

Tags: python, xml, perl, ssis

Which of these languages can transform XML into a Database the quickest?

Currently I'm using SSIS, but it's taking quite a bit of time to download large sets of XML data into the database, so I'm wondering if Python is faster for this and how much faster they are than using SSIS.  I understand that Python has built-in XML transforming, Perl is a core language, and even though these languages can accomplish the task of importing large sets of XML remotely into the server, which one of these languages do you feel is the most effective and most importantly, FASTEST way to get large sets of XML data into your server/DB?

Comment: There is [no such thing as 'PERL'](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq1.html#Whats-the-difference-between-perl-and-Perl-)

Comment: Your question asks really not what you *want*; hand-crafted assembler code is obviously the fastest. Benchmark your original program and find out where it's spending its time. Then optimize that part. If optimizing doesn't work, post it on [codreview](http://codereview.com/). If *that* doesn't work, benchmark the bottleneck code in other languages.

Comment: Re edit: Wow. I was suggesting that you spell Perl correctly, not eliminate it from your options!

Comment: @Quentin: Ok i put it back.. lol, Perl probably takes the cake, but i still think a comparison against SSIS is the most important part of this question.

Comment: I'd be fairly shocked if it doesn't turn out the database itself is the bottleneck.

Comment: Are you transforming the data before it goes into the database? Or, are you simply writing source data into a table?

Comment: Also, what is the target database platform and version & edition? What does your data model look like? How large would these documents be? Unicode or non-unicode?

Comment: Your question asks about FASTEST but you reference "large sets of XML"  Python lxml is super fast and easy but if you truly have LARGE datasets, you will need a streaming SAX like solution to keep from having to load the entire set into memory. [lxmx has iterparse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest is the one that YOU, as a programmer, will be able to tweak the most. As for me, the fastest option is SSIS, because I master that technology. Even tho I know Python, I would not be able to achieve the same level of tweaking with it.

Microsoft posted (a while ago) how to load 1TB of data under 30 minutes with SSIS. They start from textfiles, but with the hardware now available, you can clearly achieve the same (and better) with your XML source :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(v=sql.100).aspx